# Add a reaction to a message in with interaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Discord.py 2.0**
I cant add reaction in interaction message

```
@bot.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(question="Give a title")
async def poll(interaction: discord.Interaction, question: str):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f":bar_chart: {question}\n",
                        type="rich")

    message = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb)
    emoji = ("✅")
    await interaction.message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Also getting error: **discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'poll' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'**

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

```
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Comment: doesnt work giving again error **discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'poll' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `message = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb)` returns a NoneType object. In order to make your code work, you would need to send the message first and then relate to it as the "original response":

```
await interaction.response.send_message(embed = page1)
message = await interaction.original_response()
```